# not able to start business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am not able to start my business network.
**Command executed:**

```
composer network start --networkName bank --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@fabric-network --file networkadmin.card
```

**Error message:**

> Error: Error trying to start business network.
>
> Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event
> Command failed

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 16.04,
- Fabric 1.2.1,
- Composer 0.20.4

**What have I done to troubleshoot?**

- checked the logs and could not find anything
- changed the version hlfv1 to hlfv12 in connection.json

Comment: hi there, which tutorial are you using to do your project - is it this one https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org? Can you post a copy of `docker ps -a` ?  Also are you behind a firewall, did you supply an npmrcFile to the composer network install command sequence if so ?

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony,Yes, I am following the same. docker ps -a list is below. Firewall is active(checked with active and inactive).No, I haven't supply any npmrc file.hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1       "peer node start --p…"   0.0.0.0:7051-7053->7051-7053/tcp
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp
hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.1         "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp   
hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1    "orderer"                0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony,Kindly note that the status of containers is up and running

Comment: hi, not sure why you changed `hlfv1` to `hlfv12` in your connection.json file? See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/connectionprofile (see 'general information' ) - for current 1.2.x environment the profile version should remain `hlfv1` - not sure what else you've changed, or instructions you are following

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony, It is working neither with hlfv1 nor with hlfv12

Comment: hlfv12 is not a valid option. Have a look in ~/.composer/logs. It may contain some info. Also you will need to look in the peer logs as well. If the connection to the event delivery service failed then the issue will be recorded in the peer logs.

Comment: @david_k, Kindly note that I have created new fabric network from scratch. Did I miss anything after starting the network and before creation of connection profile.

Comment: I think the only way to determine what the problem is will be to review the logs and look for the reason why connection to the event delivery service of the peer(s) fails.